# Loop through columns in data.frame and make a new data.frame based on calculation in loop

Tags: r, loops, dataframe

I have a large data.frame that I want to concatenate values within the column together and then create a new data.frame with the output.  As my data.frame has nearly 1700 columns, I figured the easiest way to do this is to loop through the columns.  The following is an example of what I would like to do.

starting values:

```
variable1 = c(var1, var2, var3)
variable2 = c(var4, var5, var6)
variable3 = c(var7, var8, var9)
df = data.frame(variable1, variable2, variable3)
```

anticipated output:

```
  variable1 variable2 variable3
1 var1_var2  var4_var5  var7_var8
2 var1_var3  var4_var6  var7_var9
3 var2_var3  var5_var6  var8_var9
```

The code I'm using right now is:

```
index = 1
column = 1

Complexes <- dim(df)[2]
proteins <- dim(df)[1]


complex <-list()
interactions <- list()
complexcol <- list()

for(i in 1:Complexes){
  complex[[column]]=(for(j in 1:proteins){
    for(k in j+1:proteins){
      interactions[index] = c(paste0(corum[i,j],"_",corum[i,k]))
      index = index +1
    }
  })
  column = column + 1
  print(column)
  index = 1
}
```

When I execute, it iterates through the columns, but it's not generating the output in a new list or data.frame.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `combn` function get all combinations, making this operation a 1-liner:

```
# Build example data
(dat = data.frame(1:3, 4:6, 7:9))
#   X1.3 X4.6 X7.9
# 1    1    4    7
# 2    2    5    8
# 3    3    6    9

# Get all combinations of rows
t(apply(combn(nrow(dat), 2), 2, function(x) paste0(dat[x[1],], "_", dat[x[2],])))
#      [,1]  [,2]  [,3] 
# [1,] "1_2" "4_5" "7_8"
# [2,] "1_3" "4_6" "7_9"
# [3,] "2_3" "5_6" "8_9"
```

If you had a data frame storing factors and you wanted to combine their levels, you could convert the data frame to one that actually stores strings and then use the same code

```
# Make data frame with factors
(dat = data.frame(X=c("a", "b", "c"), Y=c("d", "e", "f"), Z=c("g", "h", "i")))
#   X Y Z
# 1 a d g
# 2 b e h
# 3 c f i
str(dat)
# 'data.frame': 3 obs. of  3 variables:
#  $ X: Factor w/ 3 levels "a","b","c": 1 2 3
#  $ Y: Factor w/ 3 levels "d","e","f": 1 2 3
#  $ Z: Factor w/ 3 levels "g","h","i": 1 2 3

# Convert to data frame with strings and then use same code
dat2 <- data.frame(lapply(dat, as.character), stringsAsFactors=F)
t(apply(combn(nrow(dat2), 2), 2, function(x) paste0(dat2[x[1],], "_", dat2[x[2],])))
#      [,1]  [,2]  [,3] 
# [1,] "a_b" "d_e" "g_h"
# [2,] "a_c" "d_f" "g_i"
# [3,] "b_c" "e_f" "h_i"
```

Comment: If the values in the data.frame are text instead of numbers, is there a way to retain and concatenate those together instead of numbers.  If I apply this to my actual data, it just reports back the addresses concatenated together.  Thanks

Comment: @JohnLapek it sounds like you actually have a data frame with factors instead of text -- see the updated question for how to handle this case. Usually I create data frames with `stringsAsFactors=F` to avoid dealing with factors during data wrangling.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to make additional contributions using the `dplyr` and `data.table` here. Being inspired by @David Arenburg, I got the following.

```
df <- data.frame(variable1 = c("var1", "var2", "var3"),
                 variable2 = c("var4", "var5", "var6"),
                 variable3 = c("var7", "var8", "var9"),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE) 

library(dplyr)
mutate_each(df, funs(combn(., 2, paste, collapse = "_")))

#  variable1 variable2 variable3
#1 var1_var2 var4_var5 var7_var8
#2 var1_var3 var4_var6 var7_var9
#3 var2_var3 var5_var6 var8_var9

library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, lapply(.SD, function(x) {combn(x, 2, paste, collapse = "_")})]

#   variable1 variable2 variable3
#1: var1_var2 var4_var5 var7_var8
#2: var1_var3 var4_var6 var7_var9
#3: var2_var3 var5_var6 var8_var9
```

Comment: @akrun I did not know that `combn` actually takes a function in it. I was trying to convert a matrix to a vector for each column in the data, but then I got stuck. When I saw David using `combn`, These ideas came into my mind.